# Is it possible to use \cancel without imports?

Tags: macros, packages, mathjax, cancel

I was writing a response to someone for a math class of mine in Piazza (a sort of chat forum for classes) when I tried to use `$$\usepackage{cancel}\cancel{x}$$` when I realized that `$$\usepackage$$` isnt recognize in piazza. Is there anyway to do something as simple as `\cancel` without an import?

Comment: I had a look at https://piazza.com/help/formatting.html. My assumption is that it is not actually LaTeX that is used. Instead, only the **LaTeX syntax** is used (a simulation of LaTeX). So I am afraid that you cannot define ypur own commands or include LaTeX packages. Does the "LaTex Equation Editor" (mentioned in https://piazza.com/help/formatting.html) provide a "cancel" feature?

Comment: Since piazza uses MathJax, I think you can either directly use `\cancel{x}`, or `\require{cancel}\cancel{x}`.

Comment: `\require{cancel}\cancel{x}` worked! thank you, if you add as an answer, i can accept. also does this work for any packages? can i import any packages in piazza with `\require`? @muzimuzhiZ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a MathJax and JavaScript problem.

Comment: @JohnD MathJax is NOT LaTeX. It just accepts part of LaTeX math markups as its input. Currently piazza uses MathJax 2.7.8, and all the built-in extensions which can be `\require`d is in this list: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions.